# Finding files iteratively in bash

Tags: bash, iteration

I am somehow failing to cp certain files iteratively to the relevant directories.

I have a directory ORIG and 3 DIRECTORIES G1 G2 and G3 where I want to use data from ORIG.

I have this:

```
i=1; for((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do;
cp ORIG/f$i'_'* G$i/;done
```

Why doesn't the star work so that I can get all the files that start with f1 to the directory G1/?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
for((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do
    cp ORIG/f$i'_'* G$i/; done
```

Pay attention to the first line. You should not write a semicolon after `do`. You can omit the "i=1", because you're already doing this in the for-loop.

This will copy files of the form "ORIG/f$i_*" to "G$i".